# How can I automatically open a file if it's the only result in grep?

Tags: bash, grep

```
[meder@kat directoryName]$ grep -RlI "send you instr" *
application/views/scripts/auth/forgot.phtml
[meder@kat directoryName]$
```

Is there a quick hack to referencing the only result? Can I somehow pipe it to vim?

Answer (score 4):

If you're OK with it opening all results in Vim, you could just do:

```
vim $(grep -RlI "send you instr" *)
```

You'll be put into a buffer with the first matching file, and can navigate to the others with `:next`.

Comment: The grep in this case would search through all of your files before the vim got to run.  If you're only interested in the first result, you could try `vim $(grep -RlI "send you instr" * | head -1)` for a speed boost.  The `head` command closes the pipe after reading the first line, signaling the grep to end early.

Answer (score 3):

Open a new file in vim and insert the found filename as a text:

```
grep -RlI "send you instr" * | vim -
```

Open the found file directly in vim:

```
grep -RlI "send you instr" * | xargs vim
```

Answer (score 1):

```
vim `grep -RlI "send you instr" *`
```